# Get LCOV compatible output from JSCover/JSCoverage coverage.xml or jscoverage.json

Tags: unit-testing, gcov, js-test-driver, lcov, jscoverage

**Summary**

I've recently switched from using [Google's JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) to [Testem](http://github.com/airportyh/testem) but miss [LCOV HTML Code Coverage Reports](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php), is there a way to convert [JSCover](http://tntim96.github.com/JSCover/) output into LCOV format, so I can [use genhtml to create reports like these](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/output/index.html).

**Detail**

I'm working from a [JSCoverage example using Testem, Jasmine and PhantomJS](https://github.com/richardbutler/testem-coverage-sandbox) which generates the 2 following coverage output formats;

coverage.xml

```
<report>
  <stats>
    <packages value="1"/>
    <classes value="1"/>
    <methods value="1"/>
    <srcfiles value="1"/>
    <srclines value="3"/>
  </stats>
  <data>
    <all name="all classes">
      <coverage type="class, %" value="100% (1/1)"/>
      <coverage type="method, %" value="100% (1/1)"/>
      <coverage type="block, %" value="100% (1/1)"/>
      <coverage type="line, %" value="100% (3/3)"/>
    </all>
  </data>
</report>
```

jscoverage.json

```
{
  "hello.js": {
    "coverage": [null, 1, 1, 1],
    "source": ["(function(exports) {", "    exports.hello = function(){", "        return \"hello world\";", "    }", "})(typeof(module) !== \"undefined\" ? module.exports : this);"]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to cover the above into the jstestdriver.conf-coverage.dat format output by js-test-driver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert JSCover output into LCOV format

Yes, see: http://tntim96.github.com/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#reportConversion

In summary

```
java -cp JSCover-all.jar jscover.report.Main --format=LCOV REPORT-DIR SRC-DIRECTORY
```